# HLS Seeking in ExoPlayer in general, live in particular

Tags: exoplayer

I am observing the following behavior using a [live stream](http://bcoveliveios-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/215102/master_english/398/master.m3u8) in a [modified PR#848](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/pull/848) for ExoPlayer: seeking backwards works perfectly whereas seeking forward works but has a multi-second delay that is not exhibited in either HLS EVENT or VOD streams.  So I am commencing an effort to find and fix this bug.  To that end, I am looking for a few sentence description of how HLS seeking works in exoplayer, merely enough to give me a kickstart in the debug effort.